# Dedicated Server emails ending up in Junk

Tags: php, smtp

I have a dedicated server that works fine. Recently I added a new domain with a new dedicated IP address. The emails from the webserver gets sent out from the primary IP address which is different from the IP address of the domain. This causes the emails to end up in the Junk email folders. Is there anything I can do changing the SMTP server to the new IP address or configuring send mail?

I need this for my php server on centos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

few things you can do to make situation better:

- make sure new ip address has valid rev-dns, one that resolves into a name that can be resolved back to that ip. try to make it not generic - so it does not contain ip address in the rev-dns name

so your 81.82.83.84 should resolve into my.name.com and my.name.com should resolve back to 81.82.83.84.

- for the domain you are sending mails from - create valid [SPF](http://www.openspf.org/) record that allows sending messages from 81.82.83.84.
- make sure that domain you send your mails from has valid MX record.
- check if your ip is in black lists and drag it out of them if needed. use for instance [this](http://www.mob.net/~ted/tools/rbl.php3) or [that](http://multirbl.valli.org/)
- from what you describe problem does not seem to be related to the mail content, but anyway - pay attention to proper headers etc.