# Solution for when your website's emails goes into yahoo or gmail spam folder

Tags: smtp, spam

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dedicated Server emails ending up in Junk](https://serverfault.com/questions/120143/dedicated-server-emails-ending-up-in-junk)

It turned out that the previous person owning this ip address that I currently have for my website had spammed a lot! so Yahoo and Gmail think that my emails are spams.

One good solution is to use a good smtp server (Like gmail smtp server), do you know any good smtp server i with high daily limits or do you have any other solutions for this problem?

Comment: check this http://serverfault.com/questions/120143/dedicated-server-emails-ending-up-in-junk or that: http://serverfault.com/questions/134518/minimize-the-chance-my-email-is-blocked-filtered-as-spam out

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want to manage it in-house, get a good server, Implement Postfix and implement suggestions from this [Email Server Test](http://www.allaboutspam.com/email-server-test). You may also want to sign up with Feedback programs with major service providers including Yahoo!, MSN, etc.
2. If you want to outsource, consider a [SMTP Relay service](http://www.safentrix.com/outbound).

Answer (score 0):

You should verify that this is actually the case, ie that your server IP address is listed in spam blocklists.

Just go to:
http://www.dnsbl.info/

If you are indeed listed in one or more black lists, then you seriously just need to get a new IP address!  Don't bother with trying to remove yourself - it'll be a long drawn out process involving proving yourself to a bunch of companies and you may find you'll never get out of some blocklists.

Complain to your hosting provider or whoever gave you the IP address - show them that it is blocklisted.  If they don't show you kindness, another IP address is only $2 a month or so anyway.

Answer (score 0):

[SocketLabs](http://www.socketlabs.com/) is a pretty popular SMTP service provider.

Answer (score 0):

Tactical solution would be to get a new IP address, but that could have the same problem.

Best solution is to get out of the SMTP business entirely and let someone else worry about delivery. We love using [postmark](http://postmarkapp.com/) here, and [amazon has an interesting new offering](http://aws.amazon.com/ses/) if you need to build your own scalable solution.

If these are marketing type emails, I'd take a hard look at folks like Mail Chimp or Constant Contact. They have APIs that you can push data to and then handle all the marketing blast type stuff.