# All my domain's outgoing mail received as spam in gmail/yahoo/hotmail

Tags: php, email, hosting, spam, gmail

All my domain's outgoing mail received as spam. I am not bulk emailing or anything like that. I know very little about how email actually works under the hood and having been continually searching for a solution. I have put a email below, the only thing I changed is the message body. If you see anthing that should be changed, please let me know.

This is the sample email:

```
Delivered-To: torontozoo@gmail.com
Received: by 10.220.188.200 with SMTP id db8cs92992vcb;
        Sun, 12 Sep 2010 14:07:21 -0700 (PDT)
Received: by 10.150.212.8 with SMTP id k8mr788303ybg.68.1284325641381;
        Sun, 12 Sep 2010 14:07:21 -0700 (PDT)
Return-Path: <---@gator1205.hostgator.com>
Received: from gateway09.websitewelcome.com (gateway09.websitewelcome.com [67.18.44.5])
        by mx.google.com with SMTP id v14si3740795ybe.22.2010.09.12.14.07.21;
        Sun, 12 Sep 2010 14:07:21 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of ---@gator1205.hostgator.com designates 67.18.44.5 as permitted sender) client-ip=67.18.44.5;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com; spf=pass (google.com: domain of ---@gator1205.hostgator.com designates 67.18.44.5 as permitted sender) smtp.mail=---@gator1205.hostgator.com
Received: (qmail 7388 invoked from network); 12 Sep 2010 21:07:20 -0000
Received: from 62.b1.354a.static.theplanet.com (HELO gator1205.hostgator.com) (74.53.177.98)
  by gateway09.websitewelcome.com with SMTP; 12 Sep 2010 21:07:20 -0000
Received: from delbalso by gator1205.hostgator.com with local (Exim 4.69)
 (envelope-from <---@gator1205.hostgator.com>)
 id 1Outlc-0006Sd-O4
 for torontozoo@gmail.com; Sun, 12 Sep 2010 16:07:16 -0500
To: torontozoo@gmail.com
Subject: --- Send/Receive Bookmarklets
X-PHP-Script: www.---/send_email.php for 142.151.130.28
From: --- <setup@--->
Reply-To: setup@---
MIME-Version: 1.0
X-Mailer: PHP/5.2.14
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
Message-Id: <E1Outlc-0006Sd-O4@gator1205.hostgator.com>
Date: Sun, 12 Sep 2010 16:07:16 -0500
X-AntiAbuse: This header was added to track abuse, please include it with any abuse report
X-AntiAbuse: Primary Hostname - gator1205.hostgator.com
X-AntiAbuse: Original Domain - gmail.com
X-AntiAbuse: Originator/Caller UID/GID - [959 957] / [47 12]
X-AntiAbuse: Sender Address Domain - gator1205.hostgator.com


Message body....
```

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Solution for when your website's emails goes into yahoo or gmail spam folder](http://serverfault.com/questions/139938/solution-for-when-your-websites-emails-goes-into-yahoo-or-gmail-spam-folder)

Answer (score 3):

The problem you are experiecning is 100% caused by your enternal IP Address being in a dynamic range. Through no fault of your own as noted in the comments of the above answers your IP block is listed on several black lists. - Please dont attempt/waste your time trying to have your IP removed as
 A - The blacklist will problerly denie your request 
 B - Your IP will likely change weekly/after a powercut/after your lease runs out.

You do however have two choices to resolve this problem.

1. Order a Static IP address from your ISP
2. Sign up to a service which provides either outgoing mail scanning / a service which allows you to use a dedicated SMTP server to deliver your mail.

If you need any more information please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Your IP of 67.18.44.5 is blacklisted on SORBS-SPAM as well as FIVETEN and LASHBACK.

Comment: If I am not paying for a dedicated IP does that mean I have to get that to ensure this won't continue?

Comment: Dynamic IPs tend to be blacklisted, shared IPs (NATted) are almost always blacklisted since there is practically always someone abusing it or is a current victim of a spambot exploit.

Answer (score 0):

This is normally because you're listed on a DNS RBL of some kind.

Use one of the online RBL checkers like the ones run by [anti-abuse](http://www.anti-abuse.org/multi-rbl-check/) or [mxtoolbox](http://www.mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx) to see if your MX IP address is listed.

And it turns out you are listed in SORBS as well as some others.

You generally have to approach each RBL to get removed from their lists, but you should understand why you are being listed and fix whatever is going wrong before you ask them to remove your listing.

Comment: Could a reason be because I don't have a dedicated IP? Would getting one be likely to solve the problem?

Comment: You're best to check with each RBL as to why you're being blocked. Being on a dynamic IP (assuming that's what you mean you're on at the moment) will be counted against you, but I think you're probably being listed for spam or spammy behaviour, based on the RBLs you're in.

Comment: Ok, I checked the SORBs listing, and it looks like your /24 netblock is listed, as well as a record for your specific IP. These were one-off events, back in June, so it's likely that some other user who had your IP sent spam, which got the IP blocked. This means that while you are being listed for spammy behaviour (although probably not yours), getting yourself your own static IP and keeping it clean is the best long-term strategy for you

Answer (score 0):

Take this [Email Server test](http://www.allaboutspam.com/email-server-test). It will tell you possible reasons your emails are going to SPAM folder and what you can do about the same.