# All my domain's outgoing mail received as spam in gmail/yahoo/hotmail

Tags: php, email, hosting, gmail

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [All my domain's outgoing mail received as spam in gmail/yahoo/hotmail](https://serverfault.com/questions/180473/all-my-domains-outgoing-mail-received-as-spam-in-gmail-yahoo-hotmail)

All my domain's outgoing mail received as spam. I am not bulk emailing or anything like that. I know very little about how email actually works under the hood and having been continually searching for a solution. I have put a email below, the only thing I changed is the message body. If you see anthing that should be changed, please let me know.

This is the sample email:

```
Delivered-To: torontozoo@gmail.com
Received: by 10.220.188.200 with SMTP id db8cs92992vcb;
        Sun, 12 Sep 2010 14:07:21 -0700 (PDT)
Received: by 10.150.212.8 with SMTP id k8mr788303ybg.68.1284325641381;
        Sun, 12 Sep 2010 14:07:21 -0700 (PDT)
Return-Path: <KeepItWith.Me@gator1205.hostgator.com>
Received: from gateway09.websitewelcome.com (gateway09.websitewelcome.com [67.18.44.5])
        by mx.google.com with SMTP id v14si3740795ybe.22.2010.09.12.14.07.21;
        Sun, 12 Sep 2010 14:07:21 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of KeepItWith.Me@gator1205.hostgator.com designates 67.18.44.5 as permitted sender) client-ip=67.18.44.5;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com; spf=pass (google.com: domain of KeepItWith.Me@gator1205.hostgator.com designates 67.18.44.5 as permitted sender) smtp.mail=KeepItWith.Me@gator1205.hostgator.com
Received: (qmail 7388 invoked from network); 12 Sep 2010 21:07:20 -0000
Received: from 62.b1.354a.static.theplanet.com (HELO gator1205.hostgator.com) (74.53.177.98)
  by gateway09.websitewelcome.com with SMTP; 12 Sep 2010 21:07:20 -0000
Received: from delbalso by gator1205.hostgator.com with local (Exim 4.69)
 (envelope-from <KeepItWith.Me@gator1205.hostgator.com>)
 id 1Outlc-0006Sd-O4
 for torontozoo@gmail.com; Sun, 12 Sep 2010 16:07:16 -0500
To: torontozoo@gmail.com
Subject: KeepItWith.Me Send/Receive Bookmarklets
X-PHP-Script: www.keepitwith.me/send_email.php for 142.151.130.28
From: KeepItWith.Me <setup@keepitwith.me>
Reply-To: setup@keepitwith.me
MIME-Version: 1.0
X-Mailer: PHP/5.2.14
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
Message-Id: <E1Outlc-0006Sd-O4@gator1205.hostgator.com>
Date: Sun, 12 Sep 2010 16:07:16 -0500
X-AntiAbuse: This header was added to track abuse, please include it with any abuse report
X-AntiAbuse: Primary Hostname - gator1205.hostgator.com
X-AntiAbuse: Original Domain - gmail.com
X-AntiAbuse: Originator/Caller UID/GID - [959 957] / [47 12]
X-AntiAbuse: Sender Address Domain - gator1205.hostgator.com


Message body....
```

Thanks.

Comment: Mike - this is more of a serverfault.com question. And, you might also try asking your web host.

Answer (score 0):

This question is impossible to answer.

Service providers don't like topublish information about how they classify messages as spam - for obvious reasons. Also there are very few standard approaches to the problem. For some of the checks they apply (particularly bayesian filtering) they may not even know why the system classifies some messages as spam. Hotmail for example, has an unpaid army of volunteers, answerable to nobody who manually train their bayesian filters.

Do get a copy of spamassassin and have a look at the methods it uses and see how these apply to your message.

After a quick look at the content you've provided, I note that:

1) the email originates from hostgator - a provider favoured by spammers (e.g. [1](http://www.plagiarismtoday.com/2008/08/21/hostgator-bites-spam/),[2](http://www.webhostingtalk.com/showthread.php?t=353748), [3](http://seo.mhvt.net/blog/?p=639))

2) the 'From' address does not match the origin of the email

3) it looks as if it's an inline HTML document rather than an attachment with inline disposition and alternate representations

4) the 'X-PHP-Script'/'X-Mailer: PHP' headers are often synonymous with UBE

HTH

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, large ISPs use a scoring system based on how many of their users report spam coming from a particular domain, IP, block, or AS, in addition to the normal scoring systems used by spamassassin.

So, its possible that this problem has nothing to do with your email or the content of your email, but your domain name or your host.

Good luck!